# How to expose a thread-safe interface that allocate resources?

Tags: c++, c, multithreading, thread-safety

I'm trying to expose a C interface for my C++ library. This notably involve functions that allow the user to create, launch, query the status, then release a background task.

The task is implemented within a C++ class, which members are protected from concurrent read/write via an `std::mutex`.

My issue comes when I expose a C interface for this background task. Basically I have say the following functions (assuming `task_t` is an opaque pointer to an actual struct containing the real task class):

```
task_t* mylib_task_create();
bool mylib_task_is_running(task_t* task);
void mylib_task_release(task_t* task);
```

**My goal is to make any concurrent usage of these functions thread-safe**, however I'm not sure exactly how, i.e. that if a client code thread calls `mylib_task_is_running()` at the same time that another thread calls `mylib_task_release()`, then everything's fine.

At first I thought about adding an `std::mutex` to the implementation of `task_t`, but that means the `delete` statement at the end of `mylib_task_release()` will have to happen while the mutex is not held, which means it doesn't completely solve the problem.

I also thought about using some sort of reference counting but I still end up against the same kind of issue where the actual delete might happen right after a hypothetical `retain()` function is called.

I feel like there should be a (relatively) simple solution to this but I can't quite put my hand on it. How can I make it so I don't have to force the client code to protect accesses to `task_t`?

Comment: Can't you just acquire the `task_t` mutex in `mylib_task_release()`?

Comment: Well the issue is, if the mutex is a member of the task_t structure, then I need to delete the task while the mutex is locked, and as per the [reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/mutex/%7Emutex), `The behavior is undefined if the mutex is owned by any thread or if any thread terminates while holding any ownership of the mutex. `

Comment: wouldn't a shared_pointer solve this problem?

Comment: @Devolus How so?

Comment: When you delete the shared pointer it is only deleted when all references are done.

Comment: As far as I can tell, this would only move the issue to the `shared_ptr` itself and would be similar to my first idea of having a mutex inside `task_t`. Yes what's pointed at by the `shared_ptr` would be alright, but I still need to return a C pointer, which I eventually need to delete. Were you thinking of something else? Or am I mistaken somewhere?

Comment: @rustyx Making this C API thread-safe is my actual goal. Indeed `task_t` gets deleted in `mylib_task_release()`, and all the function receiving a `task_t*` parameter check that it's non-null so once it's deleted, these functions are fine. The issue is if they manage to slip in the null check right before it's deleted by another thread.

Comment: Can you post a bit more of your `task_t`? And, some of the representative access functions? You can have a per-task mutex to control access to the individual task data. If you're adding to or deleting from the list of tasks, you can have a separate global mutex for that (it could be part of the _list_ control struct). Some per-task access can be done with atomics or just cache sync/flush. I've done a zillion of these impl, but a lot depends on specifics.

Comment: 'mylib_task_is_running' is almost certainly going to be unreliable anyway.  An 'onTaskCompletion()' callback would seem to be actually useful:)

Comment: @CraigEstey The mutex per task is kinda what I wanted to achieve first, but sticking it within the task seems like a no-no, and I wasn't sure where else I could store it without using a global.

Comment: You can use both types of locks. The global/list lock is for insertions/deletions from the list (e.g. for a doubly linked list, adjusting head/tail and next/prev). The per-task is atomicity with changes to a task block. You can use RCU for insert/delete: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Read-copy-update. Also, `stdatomic.h` can be used for per-task updates. Break it down: In `task_t`, what is local/bookkeeping for the task and what is status that is intertask? Local is ordinary/non-lock access. Intertask can use `stdatomic` (e.g. `atomic_compare_exchange_strong`) and no lock needed

Comment: For the global lock for list insert/delete/traversal, `pthread_rwlock_t` may be a better fit. Readers that need to traverse the list can use `pthread_rwlock_rdlock` (this allows _multiple_ simultaneous readers and _no_ insert/delete). Insert/delete can use `pthread_rwlock_wrlock` (this allows _one_ inserter/deleter and _no_ readers).

Comment: Instead of a [global] mutex, consider using a "ticket lock": https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ticket_lock I've used that [I "reinvented" it ;-) and then found that was already a known thing]. With `stdatomic`. It promotes "fairness": No high priority task can starve a lower priority task from a resource. You could implement all this in stages: Start with _one_ global lock and evolve the locks to finer grain/lockless as you gain experience

Comment: @CraigEstey Thanks, I think it's getting clearer in terms of what I'm eventually going to have to do, and that I cannot just rely on these functions with their current signature, as well as the task itself, to carve a solution out of just that.

Comment: Well, good luck. I almost forgot. Here's a simple/crude task block example that I put together as an answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64324334/how-to-share-variables-among-threads/64326906#64326906 Also, the linux kernel source would be a good resource

Answer (score 0):

if task_t is being deleted, you should ensure that nobody else has a pointer to it.

if one thread is deleting task_t and the other is trying to acquire it's mutex, it should be apparent that you should not have deleted the task_t.

shared_ptrs are a great help for this.

Comment: Thanks for providing an answer. I'm not sure how `shared_ptr` would help with what you describe since this is a C API, and how one would ensure that nobody else has a pointer to a task since this API returns the pointer and I'm not in control of what the client code does with this pointer. Does it make sense to call API functions on a task that's been released, well yes. But my main concern is that it at least doesn't crash.

Comment: I just re-read your question -- the hard case is "running() gets called while release() is supposed to release resources".  This already indicates your mutex needs to be higher-up, and since you don't want to access a Task* after its been destroyed, it hints to me that you need to keep track of which tasks are invalid.  You need a "TaskManager" class to perform synchronization and to ensure Task*'s are valid after acquiring the mutex.

Comment: Yes I'm coming to the realization that I need a higher-level mechanism to keep track of that and probably associate tasks with a mutex in a non-intrusive way.